# ¿ayuda con esta funcion en js firebase no puedo obtener el token?

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, function

error que me arroja:
          Error: Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice() must be a
          non-empty string or a non-empty array.
          at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] 
          (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28)
               at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor]
          (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:88:28)
               at new FirebaseMessagingError (/srv/node_modules/firebase- 
         admin/lib/utils/error.js:253:16)
               at Messaging.validateRegistrationTokensType 
          (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:911:19)
               at Messaging.sendToDevice (/srv/node_modules/firebase- 
          admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:532:14)
               at DeviceToken.then.result (/srv/index.js:29:28)
               at 
               at process._tickDomainCallback 
          (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

este mi codigo

```
  'use strict'
   const functions = require('firebase-functions');
   const admin=require('firebase-admin');
   admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
   exports.sendNotification =functions.database.ref
   ('/Notificaticion/{receiver_user_id}/{notification_id}')
   .onWrite((data, context)=>
  {
const receiver_user_id=context.params.receiver_user_id
const notification_id=context.params.notification_id;
console.log('tenemos una notificcacion para enviar a:',receiver_user_id);
if(!data.after.val()){
    console.log('Se ha eliminado',notification_id);
    return null;

}

   const 
   DeviceToken=admin.database()
  .ref('/perfil/{receiver_user_id}/device_token').once('value');
   return DeviceToken.then(result=>
  {
    const token_id = result.val();
    const payload = {
        notification:{
            title:"Nueva orden",
            body:'verife el pedido',
            icon:"default"
        }
    };
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id,payload)
    .then(response =>
    {
        console.log('this was a notification feature');
    });

});
```

});

donde se origina el error

```
const DeviceToken=admin.database().ref('/perfil/{receiver_user_id}/device_token').once('value');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu `token_id` es vacio, por lo que indica que la referencia con la que estas yendo a buscarlo a la base de datos esta mal

```
.ref('/perfil/{receiver_user_id}/device_token')
```

Chequea `token_id` con un breakpoint para fijarte el valor que contiene cuando hace la asignación

```
const token_id = result.val();
```

Por último, si puedes, proporciona una imagen de la base de datos y el token al que quieres acceder

Una práctica rapida para averiguar si la funcion corre como debe, es hardcodear en la funcion el token del dispositivo y fijarte si te llega, si te llega, es problema de la referencia con la que estas yendo a buscar ese token

Comment: buenas ya corregi ese error muchas gracias, lo corregi haciendo lo siguiente const DeviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/perfil/${receiver_user_id}/tokenn`).once('value');

Comment: ahora ya se ejecuta correctamente, pero no logra enviar las notificacion al dispositivo